# Can't build flutter apk for release

Tags: flutter, gradle, dart, build, apk

I can normally build a debug apk, but when I try to build a release or profile apk, I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 896

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run
with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      62.3s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

This is the line 896 in flutter.gradle :

```
project.exec {
            logging.captureStandardError LogLevel.ERROR
            executable flutterExecutable.absolutePath
            workingDir sourceDir
            if (localEngine != null) {
                args "--local-engine", localEngine
                args "--local-engine-src-path", localEngineSrcPath
            }
            if (verbose) {
                args "--verbose"
            } else {
                args "--quiet"
            }
            args "assemble"
            args "--depfile", "${intermediateDir}/flutter_build.d"
            args "--output", "${intermediateDir}"
            if (performanceMeasurementFile != null) {
                args "--performance-measurement-file=${performanceMeasurementFile}"
            }
            if (!fastStart || buildMode != "debug") {
                args "-dTargetFile=${targetPath}"
            } else {
                args "-dTargetFile=${Paths.get(flutterRoot.absolutePath, "examples", "splash", "lib", "main.dart")}"
            }
            args "-dTargetPlatform=android"
            args "-dBuildMode=${buildMode}"
            if (trackWidgetCreation != null) {
                args "-dTrackWidgetCreation=${trackWidgetCreation}"
            }
            if (splitDebugInfo != null) {
                args "-dSplitDebugInfo=${splitDebugInfo}"
            }
            if (treeShakeIcons == true) {
                args "-dTreeShakeIcons=true"
            }
            if (dartObfuscation == true) {
                args "-dDartObfuscation=true"
            }
            if (dartDefines != null) {
                args "--DartDefines=${dartDefines}"
            }
            if (bundleSkSLPath != null) {
                args "-iBundleSkSLPath=${bundleSkSLPath}"
            }
            if (extraGenSnapshotOptions != null) {
                args "--ExtraGenSnapshotOptions=${extraGenSnapshotOptions}"
            }
            if (extraFrontEndOptions != null) {
                args "--ExtraFrontEndOptions=${extraFrontEndOptions}"
            }
            args ruleNames
        }
```

I built another apps without any problems at the same laptop with the same flutter package installed.

I've read that the packages at **Pubspec.yaml** maybe the cause, so i did the following:

1- I tried to remove my packages at pubspec.yaml and rebuild the app, and it didnt work.

2- I added the same packages to another app and built it and it was built normally.

So, it seems that packages aren't the reason.

This is my Pubspec.yaml :

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.5.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  sqflite: ^1.1.7+1
  path: ^1.6.4
  path_provider: ^1.4.0
  provider: ^3.1.0+1
  http: ^0.12.2
  connectivity: ^0.4.9+2
  carousel_slider: ^2.2.1
  share: ^0.6.5
#  admob_flutter: ^0.3.4
  url_launcher: ^5.5.3
  photo_view: ^0.9.2
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
#  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.12
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
#  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2
#  firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.5.0+11
#  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.16
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.3
#  rxdart: ^0.24.1
  cached_network_image: ^2.3.1
#  in_app_purchase: ^0.3.4+5
#  firebase_mlkit_language: ^1.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter




flutter:
  fonts:
    - family:  Sons
      fonts:
       - asset: assets/fonts/Sons.ttf
       - asset: assets/fonts/sons_of_sons.ttf


  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/varty.sqlite
    - assets/images/photo.jpg
```

Comment: have you tried flutter clean? i get this error frequently and usually a few flutter clean's will do the job

Comment: I tried it many times, no change!

Comment: This is a shot in the dark but do you use custom icons for fonts? I noticed you have two font files. If yes, try running the release apk command with `--no-tree-shake-icons`, I recently had an error like this with the same line number 896. Also, when you run the debug version, does the console say something like "this application cannot tree shake icons fonts. "?

Comment: @Evan Wow, it really works, I couldn't imagine that the problem with fonts! .. Anyway, I have to add that when I tried the release at first, it didnt work, and I needed to build a debug apk then a profile then a release one.. all with this command --no-tree-shake-icons. 
Now add this comment as an answer to mark it as the correct one, and tell me what to do with the fonts? 
Thank you a lot

Comment: @ahmad Right now I am just using that flag to build release apks, I haven't debugged the issue any further since the debug apk works. Also your last statement, what do you mean by "tell me what to do with the fonts"? In my case I just have a `ttf` file like you said, and I am reading in a string iconcode from an endpoint, converting the string to an int, and then passing it into an IconData widget. And you can just fill in an answer for yourself and mark it as correct, I don't care about the reputation points or anything

Comment: @Evan I meant by my question how can we fix this, so we dont have to enter the command --no-tree...etc. Anyway, I will search for it later, its working for now, and this what I need.  Thanks again for your help, Very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evan's comment worked well and solved the problem:

> This is a shot in the dark but do you use custom icons for fonts? I
> noticed you have two font files. If yes, try running the release apk
> command with --no-tree-shake-icons, I recently had an error like this
> with the same line number 896. Also, when you run the debug version,
> does the console say something like "this application cannot tree
> shake icons fonts. "?

Just remember to build the debug apk, then profile and finally the release one with the same command.